# Documentation for \newadjustboxkey

Tags: key-value, adjustbox

The documentation for package `adjustbox` has a brief section describing `\newadjustboxkey`, but it provides no examples. I tried searching the internet, but 
Google provided only three results for the query `"\newadjustboxkey"` (maintain the quotes to reproduce the results.

Currently, I would like to define two new keys: W and H, whose semantics are, 
in the `pgf` lingo

```
W/.style={max width=#1\columnwidth} 
H/.style={max height=#1\textheight}
```

I anticipate other useful applications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key-value setting for [`adjustbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/adjustbox) is done using [`xkeyval`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xkeyval). However, there is a particular difference between the starred and non-starred version of `\newadjustboxkey`.

In this instance, you need to use the starred version and its easiest to set the `max width`/`max height` keys accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{adjustbox}

\newadjustboxkey*{W}[1]{\setkeys{adjbox}{max width=#1\columnwidth}}
\newadjustboxkey*{H}[1]{\setkeys{adjbox}{max height=#1\textheight}}

\begin{document}

\rule{.2\columnwidth}{1pt}

\adjustimage{width=.2\columnwidth}{example-image}

\adjustimage{max width=.2\columnwidth}{example-image}

\adjustimage{W=.2}{example-image}
\end{document}
```

I've added the optional (default) parameter `1` to avoid errors when a user just specifies the key `W` or `H`.